# ¿Editar y borrar la parte "off topic" de la pregunta, dejando solo la parte "on topic"?

Tags: discusión, ediciones, off-topic

Hace un par de días que se hizo esta pregunta:

[Help to analyze the ”pronombre relativo" in the sentence](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21637/help-to-analyze-the-pronombre-relativo-in-the-sentence)

La primera parte de la pregunta está bien: es una construcción algo enrevesada con mucho pronombre y puede ser complicado entenderla.
La segunda parte, en cambio, pide directamente corregir la traducción al inglés. Entiendo (por lo hablado en Meta y en otras preguntas similares) que algo así no es pertinente al sitio, y así se lo indiqué ayer a OP en un comentario.

Mis dudas:

- ¿Es correcta mi interpretación? ¿Sería *off topic* la parte que comento?
- ¿Estaría bien visto que yo mismo edite y borre la parte que pide revisar la traducción al inglés, para que la pregunta sea solo sobre los pronombres tal como dice su título?
- En general, ¿es aceptable borrar uno mismo las partes off topic de una pregunta?

Comment: I do not see the translation part as off-topic in this particular case since it contains further mini-questions about the relative pronouns. I saw it as someone trying to make doubly sure we understood his/her query.

Comment: Aparte de lo comentado por mdewey, he de destacar que la pregunta no pide realmente una traduccion ni una correccion de texto, aunque ciertamente tiene algo de ambas, y la pregunta demuestra esfuerzo previo. Creo que hiciste muy bien en comentar primero y no saltar a votar para cerrar. Hay muchos casos que son muy subjetivos y este puede ser uno. Normalmente si una pregunta tiene una parte off-topic deberia cerrarse y ser editada hasta hacerla on-topic, como sucederia si tuviese por ejemplo multiples preguntas en una sola pregunta (habria que dividirla). Cuando pueda amplio con una respuesta.

Comment: Prescindiendo del caso concreto que resultó no ser tal, sí es apropiado hacer lo que comentas. Desde el momento que se publica, el contenido puede ser editado por todos en busca de lo que mejor encaje y ayude a la comunidad en conjunto. Dado que somos un sitio pequeñito y nos tratamos con cariño, parece que lo más apropiado sea sugerirlo al autor en los comentarios, para que sea recibido mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe un cierto límite sobre hasta dónde se puede editar la pregunta de otro usuario, auqnue sea con la intención de ayudar y hacerla (más) *on-topic*.

Cuando uno se encuentra haciendo edits "salvajes" en un post cabe preguntarse hasta qué punto vamos a terminar con algo que respeta el sentido del post original, aunque generemos algo *on-topic*.

Esos edits casi siempre deben ser considerados caso a caso. No podemos tener una regla general para este caso. Como recomendaciones:

- Si "hay partes *on-topic* y partes que no, quizá hay más de una pregunta en ese post, y deba ser dividido en varias preguntas más centradas.
- Deberíamos evitar borrar sin más (Está bien borrar cosas superfluas, pero dependiendo del contenido borrado, quizá estemos *empeorando* la contribución, aunque terine siendo *on-topic*. Date cuenta de que en las [listas de revisión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review) se pueden descartar edits porque "causan daño". Si hacemos algo *on-topic* pero no conservamos el sentido original, no estamos realmente añadiendo valor al post.
- Aunque podamos ayudar con edits, no debemos descartar el uso de comentarios para ayudar al OP y recodar que sobre ellos recae la responsabilidad definitiva de hacer sus contribuciones legibles, entendibles, *on-topic* y que aporten algo a la comunidad.